# Regular expression to limit a value up to two decimal points

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, regex

I need a regular expression to use it in MVC4 for Model validation.

Regular expression should allow numbers with two decimal points 
currently I am using following expression which works but it does not allow 
user to enter integers e.g. if I enter 10 it still expect two decimal points.
I need to allow integers or maximum two decimal points if it's a float.

My expression is

```
@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
`^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$` You need the \ before the . or else you can enter any character there.

Answer (score 1):

Use this : `^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$` instead.

---

EDIT : as indicated by Rafi's comment, `.` should also be escaped...

Comment: I think the following would pass 123p13 or 12c which isn't what you want.

Comment: Escape the '.' and make it optional like the answer Rafi provided.

Comment: @Rafi hum, you're right (but it will pass 123p13 but not 12c...).